# How to compile Botan and Qt on Windows?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm writing a Qt application that uses Botan. For the Windows version I decided to use the precompiled DLL, so I downloaded the installer, installed Botan in C:\botan and added:

```
win32:INCLUDEPATH += C:/botan/include
win32:LIBS += -L"C:\botan" -lbotan
```

to my .pro file. However I'm getting linker errors (undefined reference to...) during the build process, and I can't see why - the correct .lib is specified in LIBS, the include path is fine.

I'm using MinGW.

```
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:52: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan17have_block_cipherERKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:58: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan16max_keylength_ofERKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:59: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan13block_size_ofERKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:61: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan14AutoSeeded_RNGC1Ej' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:63: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan7get_s2kERKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:64: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan3S2K14set_iterationsEj' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:65: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan3S2K15new_random_saltERNS_21RandomNumberGeneratorEj' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:67: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK5Botan3S2K10derive_keyEjRKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:68: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK5Botan3S2K10derive_keyEjRKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:69: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK5Botan3S2K10derive_keyEjRKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:83: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan10MAC_FilterC1ERKSsRKNS_11OctetStringEj' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:83: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan14Base64_EncoderC1Ebjb' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:83: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan5ChainC1EPNS_6FilterES2_S2_S2_' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:83: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan10get_cipherERKSsRKNS_11OctetStringES4_NS_10Cipher_DirE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:83: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan14Base64_EncoderC1Ebjb' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:83: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan5ChainC1EPNS_6FilterES2_S2_S2_' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:83: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4ForkC1EPNS_6FilterES2_S2_S2_' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:83: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeC1EPNS_6FilterES2_S2_S2_' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:83: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeD1Ev' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:85: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe9start_msgEv' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:83: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeD1Ev' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:86: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5BotanrsERSiRNS_4PipeE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:87: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe7end_msgEv' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:89: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe18read_all_as_stringEj' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:90: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe18read_all_as_stringEj' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:90: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeD1Ev' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:90: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeD1Ev' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:142: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan17have_block_cipherERKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:148: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan16max_keylength_ofERKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:149: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan13block_size_ofERKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:151: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan7get_s2kERKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:152: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan3S2K14set_iterationsEj' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:153: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan3S2K11change_saltERKNS_12MemoryRegionIhEE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:155: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK5Botan3S2K10derive_keyEjRKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:156: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK5Botan3S2K10derive_keyEjRKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:157: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK5Botan3S2K10derive_keyEjRKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:164: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan10MAC_FilterC1ERKSsRKNS_11OctetStringEj' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:164: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan14Base64_EncoderC1Ebjb' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:164: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan5ChainC1EPNS_6FilterES2_S2_S2_' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:164: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4ForkC1EPNS_6FilterES2_S2_S2_' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:164: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan10get_cipherERKSsRKNS_11OctetStringES4_NS_10Cipher_DirE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:164: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan14Base64_DecoderC1ENS_16Decoder_CheckingE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:164: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeC1EPNS_6FilterES2_S2_S2_' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:164: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeD1Ev' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:166: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe9start_msgEv' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:164: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeD1Ev' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:167: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5BotanrsERSiRNS_4PipeE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:168: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe7end_msgEv' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:170: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe18read_all_as_stringEj' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:174: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe18read_all_as_stringEj' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:174: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeD1Ev' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:174: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeD1Ev' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:195: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan14Base64_EncoderC1Ebjb' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:195: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeC1EPNS_6FilterES2_S2_S2_' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:196: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe11process_msgERKNS_12MemoryRegionIhEE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:197: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe15DEFAULT_MESSAGEE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:197: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe18read_all_as_stringEj' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:197: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeD1Ev' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:197: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeD1Ev' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:202: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan14Base64_DecoderC1ENS_16Decoder_CheckingE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:202: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeC1EPNS_6FilterES2_S2_S2_' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:203: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe11process_msgERKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:204: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe15DEFAULT_MESSAGEE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:204: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4Pipe8read_allEj' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:204: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeD1Ev' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o:D:\Development\Qt\silverlock-build-desktop\silverlocklib/../../Silverlock/silverlocklib/databasecrypto.cpp:204: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan4PipeD1Ev' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o: In function `LibraryInitializer': 
c:/botan/include/botan/init.h:34: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan18LibraryInitializer10initializeERKSs' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o: In function `~LibraryInitializer': 
c:/botan/include/botan/init.h:36: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5Botan18LibraryInitializer12deinitializeEv' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o: In function `~Exception': 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:25: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan9ExceptionE' 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:25: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan9ExceptionE' 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:25: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan9ExceptionE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o: In function `~Format_Error': 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:110: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan12Format_ErrorE' 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:110: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan12Format_ErrorE' 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:110: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan12Format_ErrorE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o: In function `~Decoding_Error': 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:135: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan14Decoding_ErrorE' 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:135: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan14Decoding_ErrorE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o: In function `Exception': 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:21: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan9ExceptionE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o: In function `~RandomNumberGenerator': 
c:/botan/include/botan/rng.h:78: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan21RandomNumberGeneratorE' 
c:/botan/include/botan/rng.h:78: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan21RandomNumberGeneratorE' 
c:/botan/include/botan/rng.h:78: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan21RandomNumberGeneratorE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o: In function `~AutoSeeded_RNG': 
c:/botan/include/botan/auto_rng.h:37: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan14AutoSeeded_RNGE' 
c:/botan/include/botan/auto_rng.h:37: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan14AutoSeeded_RNGE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o: In function `Algorithm_Not_Found': 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:102: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan19Algorithm_Not_FoundE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o: In function `~Algorithm_Not_Found': 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:102: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan19Algorithm_Not_FoundE' 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:102: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan19Algorithm_Not_FoundE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o: In function `Format_Error': 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:110: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan12Format_ErrorE' 
./debug\databasecrypto.o: In function `Decoding_Error': 
c:/botan/include/botan/exceptn.h:135: undefined reference to `_imp___ZTVN5Botan14Decoding_ErrorE' 
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Botan is included in QtCreator (2.x branches), you could just recompile QtCreator (or take the relevant parts), and use that. No messing with any makefiles (mingw works out of the box), and since you mention Qt, this will probably work very well.

Comment: Yes, Botan in its entirety is in the Qt Creator 2.0 sources (`src/libs/3rdparty/botan/`). I was able to compile it perfectly with Qt Creator using the provided .pro files, no errors - worked right out of the box! Thank you Nokia, and thank you rubenvb for letting me know about this. :)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, official binaries are compatible with MSVC only. I guess you should build Botan from source to use it with MinGW. According to docs it's relatively easy to do:

```
$ python configure.py
$ make
$ make check
$ make install
```

But for me compiler autodetection didn't work as expected, so I had to do few additional steps:

1. Autoconfiguration:

   ```
   $ python configure.py --cc=gcc
   ```
2. Edit generated Makefile. Replace line

   ```
   LINK_TO       = -ladvapi32.lib -luser32.lib
   ```

   with

   ```
   LINK_TO       = -ladvapi32 -luser32
   ```
3. Build

   ```
   $ make
   $ make check
   $ make install
   ```

Comment: You are correct, my failure to build Botan WAS because the provided DLL is for MSVC and not MinGW/GCC. I decided to use the Botan source from Qt Creator, though - much easier than messing with Python (which I don't want to install, and especially not the old version 2.4 that it requires) and makefiles. You get an upvote for pointing out my error, though. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've used this command to build botan using mingw32-make.exe, i've ran it in a console window with Qt support.

```
python configure.py --cc=gcc --cpu=x86 --os=mingw --without-stack-protector --amalgamation --minimized-build  --disable-shared --enable-modules=aes,aes_ssse3,auto_rng,bigint,block,cbc,ctr,des,dh,dsa,ec_group,ecdh,ecdsa,entropy,filters,hmac,mode_pad,pubkey,rsa,sha1,sha1_sse2,sha1_x86,sha2_32,sha2_32_x86,sha2_64,simd,system_rng,emsa_pkcs1,pbes2,pbkdf2 --without-documentation
mingw32-make.exe
mingw32-make.exe install
```